# Line remaining in SVG animation even when stroke removed

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to apply a stroke/draw effect to various SVG paths. However, I noticed that it was animating over an existing solid stroke. Even after removing all stroke information from the path it still appears.

How can I remove the stroke?

With

```
<path class="drawing paused" stroke="#1d1d1b"stroke-width=".2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M54.6717,187.38507a3.28086,3.28086,0,1,1,2.86088-3.25389A3.07995,3.07995,0,0,1,54.6717,187.38507Zm0-5.87372a2.65453,2.65453,0,1,0,2.22687,2.61983A2.45027,2.45027,0,0,0,54.6717,181.51135Z"></path>
```

Without

```
<path class="drawing paused" d="M54.6717,187.38507a3.28086,3.28086,0,1,1,2.86088-3.25389A3.07995,3.07995,0,0,1,54.6717,187.38507Zm0-5.87372a2.65453,2.65453,0,1,0,2.22687,2.61983A2.45027,2.45027,0,0,0,54.6717,181.51135Z"></path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realised the colour remaining can be removed using

```
fill-opacity="0"
```

Comment: `fill="none"` would be the normal way to do it.